# Add byte to byte array method optimization

Tags: c#

I have a List which contains more than 200 000 strings (each value looks like "0x01" in hex). What I am doing is that i loop on every value in List and convert that string value to a byte, which then I add to byte array. I got a problem - it lasts too long (eg 200 000 strings lasts for 16 seconds). I found this method on internet which adds a byte to existing byte array but this method seems to be very slow:

```
private byte[] addByteToArray(byte[] bArray, byte newByte)
        {
            byte[] newArray = new byte[bArray.Length + 1];
            bArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
            newArray[0] = newByte;
            return newArray;
        }
```

Do you have any idea how to make this method faster in some milliseconds and not seconds?
Thanks in advance for ideas!

Comment: that code is creating a new array and copying all data _for each item_. how about allocating one arre with the final size to begin with, and then filling that instead? also: you should include _your code_ as well.

Comment: I would change approach from "create an empty byte array and add one byte at a time" to "create a byte array that's as big as you need it to be, then populate it" (or potentially "use LINQ and just call ToArray", or "use a List<byte>` instead"

Comment: We need more context. Why are you using `Byte[]` in the first place? Where are you calling this? What does your entire application do?

Comment: `CopyTo` is very fast, I think it uses `memcpy` or something like that

Comment: Creating a new array every time for 200000 times is expensive.  Finding a way to NOT do that will be your solution.

Comment: In modern C# programming (post-.NET 4.5) I feel that any use of raw arrays outside of IO buffers is a _code-smell_. There tend to be much better collection types that signify intent better (e.g. ImmutableList, IReadOnlyList, HashSet, etc)

Comment: See [schlemiel_the_painter's_algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)

Comment: This code is fast ... but calling it 200000 times is not ... this looks like XY problem, Why you have List of hex string at the first? Why it can't be added at the end?

Comment: Did you mean to add to the beginning of the Byte array? Are you processing backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions. The reason adding the byte is slow is you are creating a new array each time. You can either create an array the same size and loop through adding the bytes at their specified index, ie `array[x] = List[x]`.

Alternatively use a List as it is optimised for adding. It has an internal capacity which is an array it allocates but it will generally over allocate its size to allow for much quicker adding versus resizing an array for each addition. It will be slower versus the above solution at first however if you clear the list and reuse it the speed should be equal to that of the array as the list has already allocated its internal array, clearing will just set the list.length to 0 but does not clear the internal array.

You can also specify the lists starting capacity using `var list = new List<byte>(200000);` which will also negate any speed impact on the first run. Note again that capacity is the internal array size used for storage behind the scenes. list.Length will return however many items you've added, not the capacity.

You can use linq to achieve this aswell which makes it very concise.

```
List<byte> bytes = hexList.Select(hexString =>Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(2,2), 16).ToList();
```

Assuming your list of hex strings is called hexList and has 0x prefixed, this is why the `.Substring` method starts on index 2, to skip the 0x

Comment: Helped me exactly as I needed :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a List which contains more than 200 000 strings (each value looks like "0x01" in hex). What I am doing is that i loop on every value in List and convert that string value to a byte, which then I add to byte array

So you have this:

```
List<String> listOfHexBytes = new List<String>() { "0x01", "0x02", "0x03", ... };
```

And you want to get `Byte[]`?

---

Unfortunately .NET doesn't have a *simple* built-in way to parse a C-style hexadecimal number, so here's a quickie (which avoids GC heap allocations by avoiding substrings):

```
static class Base16
{
        public static Byte GetNibble( Char hexDigit )
        {
            if( hexDigit >= 48 && hexDigit <=  57 ) return (Byte)( hexDigit - 48 ); // 0-9

            if( hexDigit >= 65 && hexDigit <=  90 ) return (Byte)( 10 + ( hexDigit - 65 ) ); // A-F

            if( hexDigit >= 97 && hexDigit <= 122 ) return (Byte)( 10 + ( hexDigit - 65 ) ); // a-f

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof(hexDigit), hexDigit, "Value is not a hexadecimal digit character." );
        }

        public static Byte ParseCStyleByte( String s )
        {
            if( s.Length == 4 && s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x' )
            {
                Char h = s[2]; // high nibble
                Char l = s[3]; // low nibble
                
                Byte hb = GetNibble( h );
                Byte lb = GetNibble( h );
                return ( hb << 4 ) | lb;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException( "Value \"" + s + "\" is not a C-style byte." );
            }
        }
}
```

Used like so:

```
Byte[] asByteArray = listOfHexBytes
    .Select( Base16.ParseCStyleByte )
    .ToArray();
```

Though this will cause two array copies as `ToArray` does not optimize when the input has a known length (Linq has a few boneheaded design issues...), but doing it this way also works:

```
Byte[] output = new Byte[ listOfHexBytes.Count ];
for( Int32 i = 0; i < output.Length; i++ )
{
    output[i] = Base16.ParseCStyleByte( listOfHexBytes[i] );
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32("0x01", 16)` should work fine.

Comment: Also note that in .Net Core `ToArray` does optimize when length of input is known, but your input to `ToArray` is via `Select` and that does get optimized as well.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you - I’ll take a look. The last time I checked `Select` with `ToArray` only preserved input length in trivial cases.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core, this should be reasonable, given `src` as your original list:

```
var b = src.Select(s => Byte.Parse(s.AsSpan().Slice(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).Reverse().ToArray();
```

NOTE: Since you know every string starts with `0x`, skipping that is slightly faster than using `Convert.ToByte(s, 16)`.